# How to stop getting hang of application in C# when I use Thread.sleep()

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, visual-studio, c#-4.0

I use Thread.sleep() in my application and it works good.
But it hangs my whole user interface until the sleeping time is finished. This kind of hang also found when I refresh any text of a label continuously.

```
do
{

  lbl_waiting.Text = "Waiting for 20 seconds..";

  Thread.Sleep(1000 * 60);      //// 60 seconds waiting time

  string resultFromApi = SMS.OneToOneBulk(messageHeader, SMS_number_list);

} while(myCondition);
```

in this waiting time my full user interface gets hang. I need to work this process without interrupting my frontEnd or user interface.

Comment: Why does this tagged as [tag:asp.net]?

Comment: i will use this code on my web application also

Answer (score 1):

You can go asynchronous and use [`Task.Delay()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.delay%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead:

```
async Task MyEventHandler()
{
    /// your code

    /// delay execution but don't block
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
}
```

The difference to `Thread.Sleep` is that it doesn't block.

You use `Thread.Sleep` when you want to block the current thread.

You use `Task.Delay` when you want a logical delay without blocking the current thread.

If hanging UI is a concern you should have a look into how to use asynchronous methods and async/await in your ASP.NET application. A good starting point is this article:

**[Using Asynchronous Methods in ASP.NET 4.5](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement multithreading to bypass this problem, Thread.Sleep does, indeed, stop your entire application.

Answer (score 0):

If this code is in the main application thread then it will stop the UI along with everything else.

If you need to wait between sending text messages then the sending of the messages needs to be done on a background worker thread that can be waited without blocking the UI

Comment: it also happens when i increase my counter value in any label without using threading.
For an instance

for(int i=0;i<counter;i++)
{
   label1.Refresh();
   label1.Text = "Line number : "+ i.ToString();
   label1.Refresh();
}

Comment: @ParvejBapary Yeah, that's exactly the case where updating the UI is more expensive than whatever you're actually trying to do. You don't want to force a redraw for every single item you're processing. You want to do the real work on a separate thread (or using asynchronous I/O) so that it doesn't block the UI, and only update the UI once in a while (say, once per second) to keep it responsive. `Refresh` doesn't give the application a chance to respond (`Application.DoEvents` would, but *don't* do that).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at this [dispatcherTimer class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.110).aspx)

you can make things trigger on a specific timed interval.

Importing

```
using System.Windows.Threading
```

Then setting up the timer thread

```
//  DispatcherTimer setup
DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,60); // set how often to try and run
dispatcherTimer.Start();
```

and then define the tick function as you see fit

```
private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Conditions are met)
    {
        string resultFromApi = SMS.OneToOneBulk(messageHeader, SMS_number_list);
    }
}
```